# Can I share a Facebook post?

Tags: facebook

I want to share this post:

```
https://www.facebook.com/tech.fanpage/posts/613057628737600
```

so I call this Share Dialog link:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ftech.fanpage%2Fposts%2F613057628737600
```

but I can't see the "preview" of the post (such as image, description, title, and so on). Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

There are no OG tags for those links, see Facebook Debugger Error:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Ftech.fanpage%2Fposts%2F613057628737600

Photo postings/uploads show the uploaded picture btw.

Another possibility to share stuff: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: So, how can I share a facebook post? Graph API would be ok, but I don't find any

Comment: well, you can share the link, there are just no og tags (image and stuff) :)

Comment: But if I do the same from Facebook, I can see it :O

Comment: I.E. found a facebook post that show image and stuff :O Seems that every post, if I share, don't display those infos...

Comment: can you show me that post where you see an image? maybe it´s not a post, but an uploaded picture?

Comment: It was a question :) If I go to facebook, where there is stuff, and I click "share", it works as well... it catch image and text of that post... do you understand what I mean?

Comment: yeah, but i guess that method works differently. you could also try using FB.ui feed dialogs, i will add it to the answer.

Comment: Not really.. neither the "status message" of the post can be cathed :(

Comment: well, with the fb.ui dialog you can specify everything on your own. unfortunately, there are not any more ways to share something, so i would say it´s just not possible or intended by facebook.